# Do I need an Indie Studio Name?

Tags: google-play

I've recently been making a mobile game which I'm going to publish to Google Play. Google Play requires a Developer Name. Most Google Play Developer use their game studio name like Gameloft, Supercell, etc. But some indies use their names as the developer name like Scott Cowthon, FNAF Developer. I was wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of each type to me as the only developer of my game?

Comment: The guys behind Superhot just called themselves Superhot Team. This is also an option.

Comment: Well, they are a team of more than one dev. But in my case I'm the only dev. But thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: Or you can use something inbetween and call it "Moaz Ashraf games"  or "Moaz Ashraf studios" or something along those lines.

Comment: No, doesn't really sounds good, if I'm gonna use my name, I'll use it as it is. But thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: Games for Yoaz by Moaz.

Comment: “they are a team of more than one dev” — you can be a team of one. It’s your organisation, you set the rules. That’s America baby! If you use your own name you do miss out on the opportunity to have an awesome studio name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The name is the centre focus of your entire brand, so it's something to think over carefully before you publish your first product.

Using your real name can show that personable touch you apply to your software but also has the increased risk of exposing your identity in a way that gives new meaning to the word public. I favour real names because it tends to be a lot more sensible/coherent than "Deadly Dinosaur Designs", "Banana BreadBox Banana Boom Games Bah!" or any of the other usual indie dev studio names. The most important thing though is **if your real name alliterates then you have to use it.** Scott Scotty is the kind of branding I want to see at the top of the app store tomorrow.

At the end of the day it's your call and although it represents the flag your games hoist it's not going to make or break you as a dev. The pain and permanence of naming things is why most major studios adopt a codename for their next title so they don't have to weep over what they're going to call the Unity Project for a week.

Comment: But what if I want to expand the studio later, hire an artist for example? I would have to use a name like "Banana Boom Games".

Comment: If you hire an artist under a contract then there probably wouldn't be a need to rename your entire studio to show the comradery.  If you're talking about expanding your company and getting a bunch of full time employees then you could always re-brand later. However if you think this expansion is coming fairly soon then forgoing your own name seems sensible.

Comment: But what is the risk of exposing my identity, you were talking about?

Comment: Just the general risk that everyone on the internet would be able to grab your full name quite easily. It's not really something to be that worried about since most games have credits that do exactly that. It's just people rarely watch the credits; everyone reads the studio name on the store page. You'll have to decide if that extra visibility and accountability to the product is something you're down with.

Comment: Codenames are also used to distance work in progress from the final product. You don't (or shouldn't) want your buggy, broken alpha to be associated with your brand name.

Answer (score 38):

Use your real name, or a nickname, because you're not a studio right now.

- Players have higher expectations if it looks like the game is written by a studio, and are less forgiving of rough edges.
- Interactions with your players are more friendly if they think you're a real person, and not a faceless corporate brand.
- Creating a brand is work, and you don't need to do that now. Focus on the game.
- If your game is a success, **you want your name attached to it.**

I used a brand when I started making indie games, but I wish I hadn't now.  Present yourself as you really are.

Comment: Your name will be attached to the game either way. And I personally think Seth White, Founder of Super Cool Games looks better than Seth White, Founder of Seth White Games, but that's just me :)

Comment: What about if it's a very common name? Let's say, e.g. _Jon Smith_.

Comment: @PichiWuana - use a nickname or internet handle instead.

Answer (score 6):

Well having your own name as the sole developer should only be used if you are the only one who made the game. If an artist or writer were used then you should use a studio name because that means everyone is involved. If you plan to expand and hire staff use a studio name to save on google play license costs.

So I recommend using a Studio name so later you can expand in your studio and possibly hire other people to help you create games.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As you said, I would like to expand my studio later so I will use a studio name.